# How to use manual references when inserting and retrieving relational data using MongoDb and its C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, entity-framework, mongodb-csharp-2.0

As it may be obvious of my question, I am coming from a relational database way of thinking (SQL server) and using ORMs (Entity Framework). I want to do the same things now in MongoDB and I am having some troubles with it.

Let me explain a simple scenario. Suppose we have a user, and each user can write some posts (a one-to-many relationship in SQL). So we are working with a simple case.

I've read two or three articles (and the MongoDB's original documentation) about when to use `Manual References` and `DBRef`s and when to just embed the documents within each other. And here as we are going to be needing `posts` without its `users` (like when a visitor of a website wants to see all the posts) and also `users` without the `posts` (like managing user profiles or something), I strongly believe that these two entities (documents) should be separated.

Now let's get our hands a little dirty with some code. What I do in entity framework to implement the idea above is something like this:

```
//user model
public class User 
{
    public int Id { get;set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    public User
    {
        this.Posts = new List<Post>();
    }
}

//post model
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}

//getting the data is pretty easy using entity framework
//suppose the context is created beforehand
var usersAndTheirPosts = context.Users.Include(x => x.Posts).Where(x => x.Id > 5).ToList();

//getting the first users post
List<Post> firstUserPosts = usersAndTheirPosts.FirstOrDefault().Posts;

//updating the posts that have been created after date x
foreach (var post in firstUsersPosts.Where(x => x.DataCreated > DateX))
{
    //do something with the posts
}
context.SaveChanges();  //the actual updating happens here
```

What I tried to do to implement the same thing in MongoDB was something like this (I am trying to use `Manual References` since I don't think DBRefs are a way to go for my scenario (additional unwanted overload):

```
//user class
public class User
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("posts")]
    [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
    public List<Post> Plants { get; set; }
}

//
public class Post
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("body")]
    public string Body { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("date_created")]
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("users_id")]
    public User User { get; set; }
}

//do other stuff that should be done
```

But of course, this scheme is not working and inserting a document of type `User` for example, causes the creation of very wired objects and documents (obviously)

So my ultimate question is this: How can I achieve the same functionality that I had in entity framework in MongoDB using `Manual References` and in short be able to do these two things:

1. Somehow to select the users and their posts together as above (the
   `Include` method) using a filter and Deserialize it into one `User`
   object
2. Get a user's `posts` and a post's `user` like implemented in the models that entity framework uses

Thanks in advance

Comment: As far as I know there is no easy solution. I think you will have to design it all by yourself. If you need some ideas I can help =)

Comment: @BOR4 That is so kind of you. What is your idea about how I can achieve this goal?